# Sum of two value of two array LISP

Tags: arrays, vector, lisp, common-lisp

I have two vector array :

```
t1 (vector 1 2 3) 
t2 (vector 1 2 3 6 4)
```

I just want sum the value of t1 with t2
The result is like this :

> t2 (2 4 6 6 4)

First i try this code :

```
(defun addition-v2 (t1 t2)
  (if(< (length t1) (length t2))
     (do ((x 0 (+ 1 x)))
     ((>= x (length t1)) t2)
       (setf (aref t2 x) (+ (aref t1 x) (aref t2 x))))))
```

Like you imagine the result is

```
#(2 4 6 6 4)
```

Ok fine, but how can i do if length of t1 > length of t2

Answer (score 1):

Since you destructively update t2, you can use `MAP-INTO`.

```
(defun addition-v2 (t1 t2)
  (when (> (length t1) (length t2))
    (rotatef t1 t2))
  (map-into t2 #'+ t1 t2))
```

Comment: great! :) ... you mean, use the shortest vector in place of `t2`. Also CLHS says "the fill pointer is set to the number of times function was applied" so might need to be careful about that. :)

Comment: erhm, I meant the longest. :)

Comment: Right, updated code to conditionally swap t1 and t2.  The OP used simple-vectors, so not sure if fill pointer needs to be considered.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the bottom-up & functional approach to this, here's how it would look:

```
(defun ensure-length (vec len)
  (let ((vec-len (length vec)))
    (if (< vec-len len)
        (let ((result (make-array len
                                  :initial-element 0)))
          (dotimes (i vec-len)
            (setf (elt result i)
                  (aref vec i)))
          result)
        vec)))

(defun ensure-lengths (vec1 vec2)
  (values (ensure-length vec1 (length vec2))
          (ensure-length vec2 (length vec1))))

(defun ensured-vector-add (vec1 vec2)
  (multiple-value-bind (v1 v2)
      (ensure-lengths vec1 vec2)
    (map 'vector #'+ v1 v2)))

(defun ensured-vector-+ (&rest vs)
  (reduce #'ensured-vector-add vs
          :initial-value #()))
```

Then you can just call `(ensured-vector-+ t1 t2)` or however many vectors you have.

Answer (score -2):

Finally found the problem with the size of `t1` or `t2`, in this line :

```
((>= x (length c)) t2)
```

`(>= x (length c)` need to be `< length c` so I use function `min`.

Maybe there is other solution, but this one works !

```
(defun addition-v2 (t1 t2)
  (if(< (length t1) (length t2))
     (setq c t2)
     (setq c t1))
     (do ((x 0 (+ 1 x)))
         ((>= x (min (length t1) (length t2))) c)
       (setf (aref t2 x) (+ (aref t1 x) (aref t2 x))))))
```

Comment: you can calculate the min length only once, and put it in some lexical variable as one of `do`'s inits. :) and `c` as well. Right now `c` is a special, global var - usually a programmer's error, if there's no special reason for it.

Comment: `c` is an undefined variable.